# Adobe Flex - In debug mode, what does the "(@B3FB02)" in the "value" box mean?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, debugging, actionscript, flex3

When I am debugging my application and I pause the application, looking through the debug window, there is a window which shows the name and value of all my variables.  However, for ArrayCollections, it shows something like "(@B3FB02)" instead of the value.  I know I can get the values of the various items inside the array by clicking the "+" button next to the ArrayCollection.

Is the "(@B3FB02)" the 'pointer' or 'reference' or memory address of the ArrayCollection?  What does it signify?  I've done a google search and cannot find any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the memory address of your var.

Sometimes you may have different variables pointing to the same "address" so I find this one useful :)

---

Adrian

Comment: Excellent.  In fact, that is what I was wondering.  I had two variables with the same memory address, and I wanted to make sure it wasnt duplicating the variable (i.e. copying everything twice)

Answer (score 1):

that would be the adress in memory, you are correct.